# List C++ Move to front;

Tags: c++, list

Hello i need to find the earliest note in one-Way listy 
Unfortunately i can`t use list container. 
Here some code

```
Struct

    struct Sterminarz
{
    Sterminarz *next=NULL;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
    string note;

};
```

Function which look for earliest note

```
  void findEarliest(Sterminarz *head)
{
    Sterminarz *p, *min;
    min = head;
    int counter = 0;


    for(p=head->next;p;p=p->next)
    {
        if (p->hour < min->hour)
        {
            min = p;
            counter++;  
            printNote(min, counter);

        }           
    }


}
```

And i don't know how to move earliest element to the beginning of the list without list container.

Comment: Your `struct Sterminarz` **is** a list container. Do you successfully print out the earliest element? Don't you also need to take in account the year, month, and day? Or do you want the earliest time no matter which day?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes i successfully print earliest time, No matter which day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```cpp
struct Sterminarz
{
    Sterminarz *next = NULL;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
    string note;

    bool operator<(const Sterminarz &rhs) const {
        if (year < rhs.year) return true;
        if (year > rhs.year) return false;

        if (month < rhs.month) return true;
        if (month > rhs.month) return false;

        if (day < rhs.day) return true;
        if (day > rhs.day) return false;

        return (hour < rhs.hour);

        /* alternatively:
        return std::tie(year, month, day, hour) < std::tie(rhs.year, rhs.month, rhs.day, rhs.hour);
        */
    }

    /* or, if you just want to compare hours by themselves
    bool operator<(const Sterminarz &rhs) const {
        return (hour < rhs.hour);
    }
    */
};

Sterminarz* findEarliest(Sterminarz *head, Sterminarz** beforeEarliest)
{
    if (beforeEarliest)
        *beforeEarliest = NULL;

    if (!head)
        return NULL;

    Sterminarz *p, *previous = head, *earliest = head;
    int counter = 0;

    for(p = head->next; p; p = p->next)
    {
        if (*p < *earliest)
        {
            earliest = p;
            if (beforeEarliest) *beforeEarliest = previous;
            counter++;  
            printNote(earliest, counter);
        }           
        previous = p;
    }

    return earliest;
}
```

And then you can do this to move the earliest node to the front of the list:

```cpp
Sterminarz *head;
...
Sterminarz *beforeEarliest;
Sterminarz *earliest = findEarliest(head, &beforeEarliest);
if (earliest != head)
{
    beforeEarliest->next = earliest->next;
    earliest->next = head;
    head = earliest;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/vNwvV6)

Answer (score 2):

To move a node to the front of the list, you can first remove the node from the list, then add it to the head of the list. These are both general list operations. If you haven't written a `remove()` function for your list, then you should do that now. Similarly, you should write a `add_to_head()` function or a general `add()` function.

Comment: I think maybe the problem here is that there is no list class. `Sterminarz` is a node class, and it's surprising how many learners are told to implement linked lists solely from a node class. Not surprisingly this leads to confusion about what is a node and what is a list.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried this solution, but for pass the project i need to detach the element then add it to the beginning.

Comment: @RobertPytlarczyk " i need to detach the element then add it to the beginning" Yes, that is exactly what I am suggesting. Which part are you struggling with? What have you tried? Do you know how to remove a node from a linked list? Do you know how to add a node to the beginning of the list? These are two separate operations. You should solve them one at a time.